# chrome storage sync input value

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I try to get the input value in my main.js (content script) but I struggle to finialize it somehow. I managed to save the value with the windows.onload approach as you can see below in my popup.js. But I can't get it over to the content script.
I want to use the value as a variable "userInput" in my content script.

**popup.js:**

```
function registerButtonAction(tabId, button, action) {
    // clicking button will send a message to
    // content script in the same tab as the popup
    button.addEventListener('click', () => chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, { [action]: true }));
}

function setupButtons(tabId) {
    // add click actions to each 3 buttons
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('start-btn'), 'startSearch');
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('deals-btn'), 'startDeals');
    registerButtonAction(tabId, document.getElementById('stop-btn'), 'stopSearch');
}

function injectStartSearchScript() {
    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, function (tabs) {
        // Injects JavaScript code into a page
        // chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, { file: 'main.js' });

        // add click handlers for buttons
        setupButtons(tabs[0].id);
    });
}

injectStartSearchScript();

window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('save-btn').onclick = function () {
        let valueInput = document.getElementById('deal-ipt').value;

        chrome.storage.sync.set({ 'maxBidDeal': valueInput }, function () {
            alert('Saved!');
        });
    };
};
```

**manifest.json:**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "test app",
    "description": "test desc",
    "version": "1.0",
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs", "<all_urls>", "storage"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["main.js"]
        }
    ],
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ajax.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"
}
```

**main.js:**

```
// highlight deals
async function deals() {
    // let userInputBidPrice = prompt('Set max Bid Price to show deals:');
    chrome.storage.sync.get('MaxBidDeal', function (data) {
        let userinput = data.MaxBigDeal;
        deals(userinput);
    });

    let cardCurrentBidValuesString = document.querySelectorAll('.auction > .auctionValue:nth-child(2) > .currency-coins.value');
    let cardStartBidValueString = document.querySelectorAll('.auction > .auctionStartPrice.auctionValue > .currency-coins.value');
    let cardBg = document.querySelectorAll('.rowContent.has-tap-callback');

    for (let i = 0; i < cardCurrentBidValuesString.length; i++) {
        cardsCurrentBidPrice = cardCurrentBidValuesString[i].textContent.toString().split(',').join('');
        cardsStartBidPrice = cardStartBidValueString[i].textContent.toString().split(',').join('');

        if (cardsCurrentBidPrice === '---') {
            cardsCurrentBidPrice = 0;
        }
        if (cardsStartBidPrice === '---') {
            cardsStartBidPrice = 0;
        }

        parsedCardsCurrentBidPrice = parseInt(cardsCurrentBidPrice);
        parsedCardsStartBidPrice = parseInt(cardsStartBidPrice);

        if (parsedCardsCurrentBidPrice < parseInt(userinput) && parsedCardsStartBidPrice < parseInt(userinput)) {
            cardBg[i].style['background-color'] = '#0311c3';
        }
    }
}



chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message) => {
    // choose action based on received message:
    if (message.startSearch) {
        startSearch();
    } else if (message.startDeals) {
        deals();
    }
});

// sanity check: content has loaded in the tab
console.log('content loaded');
```

So I am sure that I have to use chrome.storage.get somehow but I cant figure it out exactly.

Comment: What's wrong with using the examples in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage)?

Comment: I don’t get the value saved into a usable variable in my content script. I don’t understand how I must implement the .get so I can access it within a function in my content script.

Comment: It's asynchronous so you need to use the value inside the callback.

Comment: I have edited main.JS with what I have tried but that doesn’t work. I cannot access that variable userinput in my further code like that.

Comment: 1) Replace typographic quotes with normal quotes: `"maxBidDeal"`. 2) Use `userinput` **inside** the callback right after you assign it.

Comment: Uff that means I would have to paste all my code of the deals() function into the callback. Since it is used several times in the function. I gonna try that, thanks. The quotes came from my mobile phone that’s fixed in my code. ;-)

Comment: You can call deals(userinput) in the callback.

Comment: I have updated the "main.js" part of my first part to completely show the relevant function. Not sure if that is what u meant @wOxxOm  I get this error in extensions: `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: userinput is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is calling `deals` recursively forever without actually passing the value because you didn't declare a parameter and then you're trying to use `userinput` beyond the variable's scope.

You can promisify `chrome.storage` and use `await` like this:

```js
async function deals() {
  // Note that chrome.storage is already promisified in ManifestV3 since Chrome 95 
  let { MaxBidDeal } = await new Promise(resolve =>
    chrome.storage.sync.get('MaxBidDeal', resolve));

  // use MaxBidDeal right here
  console.log('MaxBidDeal', MaxBidDeal);
}
```

Comment: if I copy paste ur code into my content script i get this: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Error in invocation of storage.get(optional [string|array|object] keys, function callback): No matching signature.`

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're using ManifestV2, see the updated answer.

Comment: can't say THANKS enough.... it works :-) thanks for your patience! I am just learing JS and try to learn with a chrome extension project and that gave me so much headache...